# slow performance using datatables jquery plug in and brunch

Tags: jquery, datatables, brunch

So i am using Brunch as a framework for the front end of a web application.

And what I am doing is drawing each row of a table as a view and then converting the table to datatables.

I need to have each row as a view for certain ui reasons.

However, performance slows down considerably after 1000 rows.

any ideas of how i can do some kind of clever pagination or defer drawing each row of the table until later or some other idea where i can still have each row of the table as a separate view.

Comment: I've not got any experience with Brunch but regardless if you are having poor browser performance you are probably forcing updates on every insert. Make sure the entire table is built in memory before it is inserted into the dom.

Comment: What browser are you testing with? I would expect anything more than 200 rows with the datatables jquery plugin in IE<10 to have noticeably slower performance compared to other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `bDeferRender` - in your options :

```
bDeferRender: true
```

From the [docs](http://datatables.net/usage/features) :

> Deferred rendering can provide DataTables with a huge speed boost when
>   you are using an Ajax or JS data source for the table. This option,
>   when set to true, will cause DataTables to defer the creation of the
>   table elements for each row until they are needed for a draw - saving
>   a significant amount of time.

For me, it works both when inserting rows by ajax or "native"(the table is static). I have no problem with 10000 rows on a paginated table when using `bDeferRender`.